# Ошибка 6002, 6013, 6005 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

Что можно сделать с ошибками такого рода или как их полечить? Код в базе менять нельзя.

> ошибка 6002: В таблице / представлении  не определен первичный ключ. Ключ был выведен, а определение таблицы или представления было создано в режиме только для чтения.
>
> ошибка 6013: В таблице / представлении 'view_name' не указан первичный ключ и не может быть выведен допустимый первичный ключ. Эта таблица / представление исключено. Чтобы использовать объект, вам нужно будет просмотреть вашу схему, добавить правильные ключи и раскомментировать ее.
>
> ошибка 6005: Функция «...» имеет параметр «...», который имеет тип таблицы данных, который не поддерживается.

Comment: `Чтобы использовать объект, вам нужно будет просмотреть вашу схему, добавить правильные ключи и раскомментировать ее.`

Comment: @tym32167, если вы говорите о схемк в базе, то ее менять нельзя, от нее еще десктоп зависит!

Comment: @tym32167, может как то можно починить это через Entity Framework, не трогая базу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

походу есть одно единственное решение:

```
SELECT CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X.XXX)) AS INT) AS EDMXID
  FROM XXX AS X;
```